# No reverse scrolling setting in Xubuntu

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu

I just installed Xubuntu 18.04, and I've been looking for about 10 hours for the option to reverse (natural) scroll on my touchpad. It's nowhere. It's not in the Mouse and Touchpad settings.

How do I turn on natural scrolling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Terminal command**

To turn on natural scrolling : `synclient VertScrollDelta=-111`

To turn off natural scrolling : `synclient VertScrollDelta=117`